# How to get scaled coordinates within a spec from a click event?

Tags: vega

I would like to click on one of the vconcat layers of one of my vega specs (anywhere, not necessarily on a datum) and receive the coordinates corresponding to the x- and y-axis of this spec.

I have an event listener in place which gives (event, item), and I have already found that item contains the scales including an invert() function, that lets you enter pixel coordinates and returns the equivalent of the spec's x- and y-axis.

The problem now is that this invert function expects pixel cooridnates x,y = 0,0 to be at the top left corner of the part of the visualization that shows the data. The visualization however isn't at cooridnates 0,0 of the screen/view, and neither does it start with the data part, but with legend and axis titles etc.

[What the scale.value.invert() function expects as x,y=0,0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJLCO.png)

Where would I find fitting x,y coordinates / How would I get the offset to the container's left upper corner?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the required values now. For instance, I would find the corresponding x value where I clicked the visualization spec in the following way:

item.context.scales['concat_1_x'].value.invert(event.offsetX + item.bounds.x1)

Because my spec has 2 vconcat layers, I need to take the y part twice (and subtract it instead of add, since we are going from top to bottom on the y-axis):

item.context.scales['concat_1_y'].value.invert(event.offsetY - 2 * item.bounds.y1)

edit: if you have ticks on your axes, the length of these ticks needs to be added as well